# Histogram subplot for mathematical analysis of Chutes and Ladders

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Hi I've created a very simple snakes and ladders program that I want to complete numerical analysis on. I want to find the mean number of rolls it takes to win a game of chutes and laddders.

I have the data, and it works if I choose just one histogram to plot but when I try to change the number of iterations of the game Python doesn't like it and I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy as np #importing numpy
get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # importing matplotlib.pyplot
import statistics
#totalNumberOfGames = int(input("PLease enter the number of games you want to run to run:",))
numberOfGames = 1
player1Wins = 0
player2Wins = 0
player1Moves = 0
player2Moves = 0
numberOfDiceRolls = 0
gameNumberList = list()
player1MovesInEachGame = list()
player2MovesInEachGame = list()
winner = list()

while(numberOfGames <= totalNumberOfGames):

    player1 = 0
    player2 = 0

    a = range(1,11);b = range(11,21)[::-1];c = range(21,31);d = range(31,41)[::-1];e = range(41,51);f = range(51,61)[::-1];g = range(61,71);
    h = range(71,81)[::-1];i = range(81,91);j = range(91,101)[::-1]
    #print ("Snakes and Ladders game")
    #print (j,'\n',i,'\n',h,'\n',g,'\n',f,'\n',e,'\n',d,'\n',c,'\n',b,'\n',a)

    def check_for_snakes_and_ladders(n):
        #This method checks for the presence of snakes or ladders on the board
        ladders = {1:26,5:15,11:36,21:42,28:84,36:44,51:67,71:91,80:100}
        snakes = {98:78,95:75,93:73,87:24,64:60,62:19,56:53,49:11,48:26,16:6}
        if n in ladders:
            #print("Its a ladder,Climb up")
            n = ladders[n]
        elif n in snakes:
            #print("Its a snake!!,Come down")
            n = snakes[n]
        return n


    def roll_dice(r,numberOfDiceRolls):
        #This method takes input from each of the players, #prints the current position of the players and checks for the winner of the game
        d = np.random.randint(1,7)
        #print('you have rolled', d)
        d = r + d 
        numberOfDiceRolls += 1
        return d


    while (player1 < 100 or player2 < 100):
        #print ("Its turn of player1\n")
        player1 = roll_dice(player1,numberOfDiceRolls)
        player1Moves += 1
        player1 = check_for_snakes_and_ladders(player1)
        #print ("Current status of Player1:",player1,"and Player2:",player2)
        #print ('Player 1 moves', player1Moves)
        #print ('Player 2 moves', player2Moves)
        if (player1 > 99):
            winner.append(1)
            #print ("Winner of the game is player1")
            break

        #print ("Its turn of player2\n")
        player2 = roll_dice(player2,numberOfDiceRolls)
        player2Moves += 1
        player2 = check_for_snakes_and_ladders(player2)
        #print ("Current status of Player1:",player1," and Player2:",player2)

        if (player2 > 99):
            winner.append(1)
            #print ("Winner of the game is player2")
            break
    gameNumberList.append(numberOfGames)
    numberOfGames += 1
    ##print ('Player 1 moves', player1Moves)
    ##print ('Player 2 moves', player2Moves)
    #print(winner)
    #print("-"*50)

    player1MovesInEachGame.append(player1Moves)
    player2MovesInEachGame.append(player2Moves)
    player1Moves = 0
    player2Moves = 0

##print("-"*20," Data Analysis ","-"*20)    
for n in winner:
    if (n == 1):
        player1Wins += 1
    elif (n == 2):
        player2Wins += 1
print("Player 1 won",player1Wins,"times")
#print("Player 2 won",player2Wins,"times")
#print(gameNumberList)


# 

# In[30]:

num_bins = 100
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
ax0, ax1, ax2 = axes.flatten()

def hist0(totalNumberOfGames):
    totalNumberOfGames = 100
    mu0 = statistics.mean(player1MovesInEachGame)
    print("Mean amount of rolls is: ",mu0,)
    sigma0 = statistics.stdev(player1MovesInEachGame)
    print("The standard deviation of this data set is: ",sigma0,)

# the histogram of the data
    n, bins, patches = ax0.hist(player1MovesInEachGame, num_bins, normed=1, 
                           stacked = True, color = 'red', label = 'Turns to Win')

# add a 'best fit' line
    y = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu0, sigma0)
    ax0.plot(bins, y, '-', color = 'y', label = 'Standard Deviation of Turns')
    ax0.set_xlim(5,120)
    ax0.set_xlabel('Turns')
    ax0.set_ylabel('Probability density')
    ax0.set_title('Percentage of Finished Games in n-turns')
    ax0.legend(prop={'size': 10})

def hist1(totalNumberOfGames):
    totalNumberOfGames = 500
    mu1 = statistics.mean(player1MovesInEachGame)
    print("Mean amount of rolls is: ",mu1,)
    sigma1 = statistics.stdev(player1MovesInEachGame)
    print("The standard deviation of this data set is: ",sigma1,)

# the histogram of the data
    n, bins, patches = ax1.hist(player1MovesInEachGame, num_bins, normed=1, 
                           stacked = True, color = 'red', label = 'Turns to Win')

# add a 'best fit' line
    y = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu1, sigma1)
    ax1.plot(bins, y, '-', color = 'y', label = 'Standard Deviation of Turns')
    ax1.set_xlim(5,120)
    ax1.set_xlabel('Turns')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Probability density')
    ax1.set_title('Percentage of Finished Games in n-turns')
    ax1.legend(prop={'size': 10})

def hist2(totalNumberOfGames):
    totalNumberOfGames = 500
    mu2 = statistics.mean(player1MovesInEachGame)
    print("Mean amount of rolls is: ",mu2,)
    sigma2 = statistics.stdev(player1MovesInEachGame)
    print("The standard deviation of this data set is: ",sigma2,)

# the histogram of the data
    n, bins, patches = ax2.hist(player1MovesInEachGame, num_bins, normed=1, 
                           stacked = True, color = 'red', label = 'Turns to Win')

# add a 'best fit' line
    y = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu2, sigma2)
    ax2.plot(bins, y, '-', color = 'y', label = 'Standard Deviation of Turns')
    ax2.set_xlim(5,120)
    ax2.set_xlabel('Turns')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Probability density')
    ax2.set_title('Percentage of Finished Games in n-turns')
    ax2.legend(prop={'size': 10})
# Tweak spacing to prevent clipping of ylabel
    fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()

def main():
    hist0(totalNumberOfGames)
    hist1(totalNumberOfGames)
    hist2(totalNumberOfGames)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Error**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 106, in 
>       ax0, ax1, ax2 = axes.flatten()
>
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a subplot grid with 2 rows and 2 columns. 2 times 2 gives 4.
Now using `ax0, ax1, ax2 = axes.flatten()` you're trying to assing 4 values to 3 variables.

Use

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
ax0, ax1, ax2, forgottenaxes = axes.flatten()
```

or directly

```
fig, (ax0, ax1, ax2, forgottenaxes) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
```

Comment: That solution works, but its doesn't plot anything, I'm trying to change the number of iterations the game goes through, I want a histogram for 100 iterations, a second for 500, a third for 10000 and a fourth for 1000000.

Comment: My aim is to see how the mean changes with the amount of iterations of the game.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't plot anything"? Please be precise.

Comment: [![Screenshot at 2017-03-31 18-08-39.png](https://s2.postimg.org/rxf9o3wjd/Screenshot_at_2017-03-31_18-08-39.png)](https://postimg.org/image/5lhgupxf9/)

Comment: So you do get a plot; which is not *not anything*!! The problem is that you call `plt.show` before the games start, so the plot is empty.